# prevent the replacement of composer packages by meta package

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php

Say I wanted to use individual ZF2 modules, e.g. `zendframework/zend-mvc`, and not the whole collection (`zendframework/zf2`). Say that I'd also want to use some third party module that relies on ZF2, but it requires the "meta" package like so:

```
"require": {
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*"
}
```

instead of only specifying the modules it actually uses. This creates a situation where my individual package requirements like:

```
    "zendframework/zend-modulemanager": "2.3.*",
    "zendframework/zend-mvc": "2.3.*",
```

are overwritten by the meta packages:

```
"replace": {
    ...
    "zendframework/zend-modulemanager": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-mvc": "self.version",
    ...
}
```

So I end up with the whole thing instead of just the selected modules I want.

Is it possible to prevent the replacement? If so, then how? Is it possible without ignoring the dependencies of the "offending" package altogether?

The reason I want to do this is twofold: I want less code in my vendors dir and don't get any false alarms when some package that I don't actually use ends up flagged as vulnerable or unstable.

A follow up question: could anyone weight in on autoloader performance gains (if any) when only part of framework is required?

reference:
[zf2 manifest](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/composer.json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to fork the third party module in question, change the requirements and submit a pull request back to the author. If the author isn't quick to merge PRs you can use your forked version in the meantime.

I'd be very surprised if you saw any performance gain from using only part of the framework.

Comment: That sounds like the proper way to go about it, but it would be useful to do this without PR-ing vendor packages maintainers (me being lazy and all). As for the performance thing, I was thinking mainly about the class map that the composer autoloader seems to hit first -- less classes = smaller  class map array and that could (?) improve lookup times.

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's any other way than this.